# selecting all cells in excel sheet from an offset (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

So I am creating an excel report from an access database. So this is done in access VBA.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub ExportActiveSheet()

   'irrelevant data


   'get the info
   ExcelSheet.Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rs




   Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

so now, as you can see.. my recordset gets copied to a range starting from A3. I have an unknown number of columns (right now, user can select between 1 column to 36 columns, but this can grow. Again this should be irrelevant).

I want to select everything from A3 till the end of the worksheet (or, even better only the rows where there is data) and change the row height.

I  have tried:

```
    ExcelSheet.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(10000, 40)).Select
    With ExcelApp.Selection
        .RowHeight = 22.5
    End With
```

but it gives me a `Method Range of object _worksheet failed` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Select

With Selection
     .RowHeight = 20
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 With ExcelSheet
        .Cells.RowHeight = 22.5
        .Cells.Font.name = "Ariel"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 8.5
end with
```

and then i just changed the stuff (titles, headers) to what I wanted. Much easier. **I will mark my own answer as the correct one in 2 days**